# How do you detect the URL in a Java Servlet when forwarding to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet that looks something like this:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println(request.getPathInfo());
    }
}
```

with a web.xml mapping like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/example/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and it gives me exactly what I expect... If I go to http://localhost:8080/example/foo it prints "/foo". However, if I change the servlet to forward to a JSP file:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // do something here to check the value of request.getPathInfo()
        request.getRequestDispatcher("whatever.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

then when I check the value of getPathInfo() it now reports "whatever.jsp" instead of "foo".

1. Why has this changed before it's been forwarded to the JSP?
2. How can I detect what URL the user's looking for?

**EDIT:** Just in case it matters this is on Google App Engine. Don't think it should though.

Comment: At the second case, are you checking the getPathInfo before or after the forward request? Or you do that in the jsp file?

Comment: I'm doing it before, where I put the comment in. (// do something here to check the value of request.getPathInfo())

Answer (score 16):

The question is vague and ambiguous (is the servlet calling itself on every forward again?), but it much sounds like that you need `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")`.

Answer (score 2):

The URL the user (browser) requested can be accessed from the request by:

```
request.getRequestURL()
```

Alternatively the request has a [whole bunch of accessors](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to get the various pieces of the URL as well as those on [ServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

To redirect to a different URL change the response rather than the request:

```
response.sendRedirect(theURLToRedirectTo)
```

Comment: Well, I'm actually using one of those above, getPathInfo(). The docs for it say: "Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request." but that clearly isn't what's happening.

Comment: Why not? Was "/foo" not the extra path? or was "whatever.jsp" not the extra path. Both of these were the extra paths in your case.

Comment: It was showing the JSP as the path, not foo. I don't see how it COULD be the JSP since I'm asking for it in the servlet, before I'm sending the forward to the JSP.