# How to get the original request url from a servlet/jsp after multiple servlet forwards

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, struts, tiles

I am working on a cruise booking app using struts/tiles that uses **multiple** internal servlet/jsp forwards to reach the right jsp for display. But, once you reach the final jsp that is used to render the page, the `${pageContext.request.requestURL}` call in that jsp returns the path of **this** jsp.

For example

1. Original request:  **/booking/getCruiseDetails**
2. gets forwarded to: /booking/validateCruiseDeteails.jsp
3. gets forwarded to: /booking/validateUser.jsp
4. finally gets forwarded to: **/booking/showCruiseDetails.jsp**

So, in /booking/showCruiseDetails.jsp when I call `${pageContext.request.requestURL}` I
get /booking/showCruiseDetails.jsp

How do you get the the original (client made) request url from a jsp that has been reached through **multiple** forwards.  I did find the following posts on stackoverflow that hint at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989888/get-request-url-from-jsp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089528/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-client), but they don't address how you would go about finding the original request url after multiple forwards have occurred.

Comment: Multiple forwards inside JSPs is an extremely bad design.

Comment: agreed...but I am dealing with legacy code ;-(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found a better answer in this post [ [How do you detect the URL in a Java Servlet when forwarding to JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030798/how-do-you-detect-the-url-in-a-java-servlet-when-forwarding-to-jsp) ]

On the target JSP use:

`request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")`

To find out what the original URL was.

It doesn't require you to take any extra steps on the forwarding servlet

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the accepted one. The servlet specification guarantees that this propertly survives multiple forwards:  

"Note that these attributes must always reflect the information in the original request even under the situation that multiple forwards and subsequent includes are called." 
(Servlet specification, 9.4.2: Forwarded Request Parameters)

Comment: Hey thanks, But how can i get the parameters it only prints the request

Comment: In Spring Boot 3 `request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.forward.request_uri")` or `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)` works for me.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a filter to putting origin address to request attribute and then read it from jsp

Filter mapped to /booking/* execute:

```
request.setAttribute("origin", request.getRequestURL());
```

Jsp:

```
${pageContext.request.attribute["origin"]}
```

This works because filter has set REQUEST dispatcher by default. It means filter executes only for direct client requests not for forwarding/including

Comment: i'll try this out, and if it works i'll accept it as the answer. In the meantime, i've given it an up vote :-)

Comment: I'll be very happy if this solution'll help you

Comment: BTW, could you kindly explain what you mean, when you say "this works because filter has set REQUEST dispatcher by default"? thnx (and haven't gotten to validating your suggest just yet)

Comment: nevermind, I think you were referring to the <dispatcher> config property in the filter mappings...

Comment: exactly, dispatcher in filter-mapping. We have 3 modes: request, forward or include

Comment: The comment below, that uses "request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")" is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Same as @Lenny Markus but using the provided constant in the Request Dispatcher class.

```
request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
${requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"]}
```

or with single quotes

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using servlet filters instead to validate information.  This means you can avoid your validation forwarding and just stay in a single JSP file.

Comment: That's great advice, but I am dealing with a legacy app and so am bound by its architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it without using a bean reference with the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}" />
```

Of course, you need to map the 404 page in your web.xml file though.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/xhtml/pg/error/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```