# Need to `location.href` value in JSTL(or JSP)

Tags: spring, tiles

All I need is just `<script>location.href</script>` value in JSTL(or JSP).

Just same as the web browswers display. But it's not that easy.

I'm using `Tiles2` and `request.getRequestURL()` shows `tiles` base jsp location like `/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp...`

And I found `<%=request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")%>` shows what I want.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387378/411615

But still it's not enough. it's not showing protocol and domain. 
And I searched again.

`http://${pageContext.request.localName}<%=request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")%`>

It looks dirty and does not contain **parameters**. I would make it like this...

```
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
    for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
        ...
    }
```

But it's weird. In javascript it's so simple, but in JSP it's very tough.

Is there any neat way?

My environment is`Spring 3.1, Tiles2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Request object is all you get on the server side. There's no way to know what was in the original href link because the browser sends the fully assembled URL to the server. Your options are 1) use some javascript trickery on the client side to send the original href as a parameter or header value, or 2) poke around in the Request object to get what you need. 2) is better.